# xuggler: no error but , file still not converted to 3gp

Tags: video-encoding, 3gp, xuggler

i am using xuggler to convert file to 3gp format. Now afetr a lot of googling i have come to a point where i get no error on the console but the converted file is just 65Kbs as opposed to the 3Mb source file and if i try to play it , it says the file has no playable streams. Its a simple program that should just convert the file and stop , but it keeps on working as if its busy, but after enabling debug , the debug output on console just stops and nothing happens. Here is the console output

> 2011-09-13 11:06:21,551 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onOpen()
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,556 [main] DEBUG com.xuggle.xuggler - Closing dangling Container (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:83)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,580 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAddStream(0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,581 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAddStream(1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,697 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onOpenStream(0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,700 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onOpenStream(1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,702 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWriteHeader()
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,703 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877078776[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:440000;complete:true;num samples:200;size:400;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,704 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877078152[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:465122;complete:true;num samples:208;size:416;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,705 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877078152[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:491244;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,717 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898647008[complete:true;dts:440000;pts:440000;size:25749;key:true;flags:1;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,718 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877121728[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:440000;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,723 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1877553928[complete:true;dts:473367;pts:473367;size:15732;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,724 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009568[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:473367;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,728 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898734664[complete:true;dts:506733;pts:506733;size:12211;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,729 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009568[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:506733;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,737 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898792584[complete:true;dts:540100;pts:540100;size:12179;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,738 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009568[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:540100;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,742 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898779032[complete:true;dts:573467;pts:573467;size:11425;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,743 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009568[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:573467;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,747 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1877553928[complete:true;dts:606833;pts:606833;size:13114;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,748 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009568[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:606833;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,752 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898647008[complete:true;dts:640200;pts:640200;size:13063;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,753 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009568[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:640200;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,754 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877013536[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:517492;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,755 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1898957664[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:543739;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,756 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877009728[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:569987;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,761 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898734664[complete:true;dts:673567;pts:673567;size:12108;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,761 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877121728[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:673567;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,766 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1877018296[complete:true;dts:706933;pts:706933;size:11122;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,766 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009568[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:706933;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,767 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1898952704[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:596234;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,768 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877013536[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:622482;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,769 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1898957664[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:648729;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,774 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898734664[complete:true;dts:740300;pts:740300;size:11072;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,774 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877121728[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:740300;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,778 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898647008[complete:true;dts:773667;pts:773667;size:10359;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,779 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009568[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:773667;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,783 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1877018296[complete:true;dts:807033;pts:807033;size:10871;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,786 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877121728[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:807033;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,790 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1897935648[complete:true;dts:3520;pts:3520;size:662;key:true;flags:1;stream index:1;duration:1024;position:-1;time base:1/8000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,791 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877009728[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:674977;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,792 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1898952704[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:701224;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,793 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877013536[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:727471;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,797 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898792584[complete:true;dts:840400;pts:840400;size:29105;key:true;flags:1;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,798 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009840[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:840400;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,802 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1877018296[complete:true;dts:873767;pts:873767;size:9525;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,803 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009840[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:873767;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,806 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898792584[complete:true;dts:907133;pts:907133;size:6788;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,807 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009840[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:907133;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,808 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1898957664[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:753719;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:21,809 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877009728[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:779966;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,884 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1897998320[complete:true;dts:4553;pts:4553;size:18;key:true;flags:1;stream index:1;duration:1024;position:-1;time base:1/8000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,885 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1898952704[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:806214;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,888 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1877008432[complete:true;dts:940500;pts:940500;size:9728;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,889 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009840[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:940500;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,893 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898647008[complete:true;dts:973867;pts:973867;size:10757;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,893 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009840[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:973867;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,894 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877013536[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:832461;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,895 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1898957664[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:858709;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,896 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1877009728[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:884956;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,900 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1877553928[complete:true;dts:1007233;pts:1007233;size:9689;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,900 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009840[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:1007233;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,905 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1877079312[complete:true;dts:1040600;pts:1040600;size:15668;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,905 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009840[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:1040600;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,909 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onWritePacket(com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket@-1898647008[complete:true;dts:1073967;pts:1073967;size:14610;key:false;flags:0;stream index:0;duration:1;position:-1;time base:1/1000000;])
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,910 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onVideoPicture(com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture@-1877009840[pixel type:YUV420P;width:320;height:240;time stamp:1073967;complete:true;size:115200;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], null, 0)
>   2011-09-13 11:06:22,911 [main] DEBUG c.x.mediatool.MediaDebugListener - onAudioSamples(com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples@-1898952704[sample rate:8000;channels:1;format:FMT_S16;time stamp:911204;complete:true;num samples:209;size:418;key:true;time base:1/1000000;], 1)